# How do I test that a method calculates the correct result?

Tags: java, testing

This sounds more vague than I mean, but when testing a method in a class what is the correct process.

e.g. a customer class saves a set password's md5 hash to the db, not the actual password. A private method in the customer class works out the md5 hash for saving.

```
public class Customer() {

public void setPassword(String password){
  this.password = hashPassword(password);
}

private String hashPassword(String password){
  ..do stuff..
}

.. other methods ..

}
```

Now this is just an example, I don't want to know about how to calculate the md5 hash etc. It's about the testing. Here's my options I can think of:

- I create a method in the test class that does the same as hashPassword and then compare the results.
- I manually calculate what the outcome would be for a specific password (myPassword) and store as a constant. After setting the password to myPassword in the test I would compare the constant to the result.

Comment: I know this isn't the point, but most likely you shouldn't be using MD5 for password hashing, and also add a salt.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. This is a mini project just to serve as a back end to learn Android. But I'll look at SHA algorithms etc in future to improve the quality of the end product, even its just just a demo.

Comment: Note that while there are important questions about testing private methods (and specifically what the desire to test a private method tells you about your program's design), the privateness of the method seems to have no bearing on this particular question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take the second option, i.e. pre-calculate a value or a sequence of values, and test with them. Testing a method with a copy of the same method serves no purpose other than increasing the amount of code duplication.

Comment: What about cases where it's very impractical to the pre-calculation by hand? E.g. when testing code that inverses or multiplies matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Do this

> I manually calculate what the outcome would be for a specific password (myPassword) and store as a constant. After setting the password to myPassword in the test I would compare the constant to the result.

There is no point in testing an implementation by comparing it to the results of the same exact implementation.

Comment: *"There is no point in testing an implementation by comparing it to the results of the same exact implementation"* It could help if you later decide to replace of modify the implementation. The one in the test would help identify if the new implementation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the same algorithm, since you would probably implement the same bugs in the two implementations. I would not manually compute since this manual computation might be wrong. Instead, I would use some reference inputs and check that the output of your algorithm is the same as the reference output. See [the following page](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321#appendix-A.5):

```
MD5 test suite:
MD5 ("") = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 ("a") = 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
MD5 ("abc") = 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
MD5 ("message digest") = f96b697d7cb7938d525a2f31aaf161d0
MD5 ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b
MD5 ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") =
d174ab98d277d9f5a5611c2c9f419d9f
MD5 ("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
78901234567890") = 57edf4a22be3c955ac49da2e2107b67a
```

Now, if you trust your implementation of MD5, and just want to check that the digester is called, you could inject a mock MD5 digester, and check that the mock digester is called when you set the password.

Comment: Although I wasn't asking specifically for md5 testing help, this is really useful and I'll definitely implement it in my tests. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely take the second approach.  The last thing that you want is to have your test code duplicating functionality in the "unit under test".

1. Store a list of known plain text and hashed results.
2. Add a test that calls `setPassword` with the plain text
3. Add a method to "check" the hashed value - make this one package visible if you are adding it for testing

The bonus here is that **you are not testing the `hashPassword` method**.  You are verifying that a password is hashed correctly.  Your test code shouldn't even know or care that the private method is there.  I would question whether you should be testing that passwords are hashed at all since it is really an implementation secret of the `Customer` class, but you may have good reasons for testing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3th option too.

You can use the [JunitAddons](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net) library, it will allow you to test private methods using reflection, but it hides the complexity of reflection for you.

Example: To set the value of an object obj to 100 via the method setValue():

```
PrivateAccessor.invoke( obj, "setValue", new Class[]{int.class}, new Object[]{
    new Integer( 100 )} );
```

The value returned by the method is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

From your options option number 2 I would calculate it using i.e. openssl and store it, for later comparsion :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to test private method because it contains some important logic. Maybe the best possible approach would be to move body of that method to some outer class?

Your code snippet is good example - counting MD5 should be done outside of Customer class - this is not the responsibility of something called Customer.

```
private String hashPassword(String password) {
    this.hash = PasswordHasher.hash(password)
}
```

and later `public(or default/protected) String PasswordHasher#hash(String)` is easy for being tested